# Что за warnings в rkhunter ubuntu desktop и что за вирус такой живучий в Windows 11?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Начну с предыстории. На компьютере стояла лицензионная Windows 11. Каким-то образом поймал серьезный вирус, который устанавливал везде кейлогеры, сторонние программы, показывал рекламу, открывал сам вкладки браузера и тд. Пытались сбросить Виндоус до заводских настроек через Параметры системы. После переустановки вирус остался каким-то образом в системе. Из-за этого решили поставить Линукс, а именно Убунту 22.04. Каким образом устанавливали Убунту:

1. Скачали iso Ubuntu 22.04 desktop на этом же зараженном компьютере.
2. Создали раздел жесткого диска.
3. Распаковали файлы iso в созданный раздел.
4. Перезапустили компьютер.
5. Во время загрузки компьютера нажали F8 и открылось меню голубого цвета с элементами, похожими на Виндоус.
6. Оттуда выбрали загрузчик Убунту и зашли в Установочник системы Убунту.
7. Оттуда отфарматировали все диски, поменяли все на FAT32 и установили систему.

После всех махинаций встали вопросы:

1. Если вирус выжил даже после сброса системы Виндоус до заводских настроек, есть ли вероятность что вирус успел каким-то образом установиться в Убунту во время установки самой Убунту?
2. После установки системы Убунту, мы ею попользовались 3 дня, и решили запустить проверку системы утилитой под названием rkhunter. Во время проверки выскачило 2 warnings:

   Checking for suspicious (large) shared memory segments [ Warning ]

   Checking /dev for suspicious file types [ Warning ]

Пробовал через безопасный режим Windows запустить 3 сканера: касперский, cureit! и Malwebytes - ничего не нашлось. Еще когда запускал безопасный режим, то выдавалась ошибка: "cftmon.exe - Обнаружено переполнение стекового буфера в данном приложении. Это переполнение может позволить злоумышленнику получить управление над приложением.".

Скажите пожалуйста, что делать? Есть ли вероятность, что вирус перешол на Убунту? Меня беспокоит и следующий вопрос: может ли вирус Виндоус каким-то образом передать Линукс-вирус на систему Убунту во время ее установки?

Старался очень подробно все расписать. Помогите пожалуйста. Благодарю.

Comment: Ну если ты прям боишься - сделай загрузочную флэшку с Убунтой на другом компе и переставь на своём всё с нуля. С удалением разделов и прочим. На счёт вируса. Ну тут надо смотреть куда конкретный виртус может пробраться, потому что современные системы с UEFI могут быть атакован через этот самый UEFI и тогда похрен сколько раз ты будешь всё переставлять - вирус засел в биосе. Ищи инфу конкретно по твоему зловреду на профильных ресурсах.